# approach to show an auto-incremental ID on form?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have a requirement show  auto increment value on form when user click "Add New" link and 
this value is came from table  AUTO_INCREMENT primary column.

First idea is to retrieve max record and sum 1 on max value,but it failed on multiple users are logging,so i don't go with that.

another one  when user click "Add New"link insert new record with time stamp and get this record id and show on form and if user not interested to add new then on cancel button we remove this id from database.

can this is correct approach to do this task or another way that i don't know which is MySQL provided.please suggest any option or i will proceed with my given option.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, this is an odd requirement...any chance you can get around it? I am not sure there is a way to can 'reserve' an ID for a record that has not yet been added to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_insert_id()` - see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Just run your query (without setting the field), and then put `mysql_insert_id()` after it, and it will give you the auto-incremented ID that you've inserted to.

Comment: i have doubt that three user are logged and use same link with same time,then what is the behavior of  mysql_insert_id()?

Comment: When you `insert` to a MySQL database, it'll save the inserting ID that it used for **that** query that it just did. Doesn't matter if the script is called a thousand times at the exact same second, it's for the query called just before it. You grab this value using `mysql_insert_id()`.

Comment: @sam - It is the same concept as running an `INSERT` with cfquery and using `result_name.GENERATED_KEY` to retrieve the ID of the new record. But I agree the requirement seems strange. Why does the user need to "see" the database ID value?